# Mysql insert into with select distinct

Tags: java, mysql, select, insert, distinct

i'm using java with mysql,i have this code in mysql

`SELECT DISTINCT date(datecreat) as datetemp
, (SELECT max(sensortemp) FROM akdb.iotdatas WHERE date(datecreat)=datetemp ) as maxt
, (SELECT min(sensortemp) FROM akdb.iotdatas WHERE date(datecreat)=datetemp ) as mint
, (SELECT avg(sensortemp) FROM akdb.iotdatas WHERE date(datecreat)=datetemp ) as avgt
, (SELECT max(sensorhum) FROM akdb.iotdatas WHERE date(datecreat)=datetemp ) as maxh
, (SELECT min(sensorhum) FROM akdb.iotdatas WHERE date(datecreat)=datetemp ) as minh
, (SELECT avg(sensorhum) FROM akdb.iotdatas WHERE date(datecreat)=datetemp ) as avgh
, (SELECT max(sensorpres) FROM akdb.iotdatas WHERE date(datecreat)=datetemp ) as maxp
, (SELECT min(sensorpres) FROM akdb.iotdatas WHERE date(datecreat)=datetemp ) as minp
, (SELECT avg(sensorpres) FROM akdb.iotdatas WHERE date(datecreat)=datetemp ) as avgp  FROM akdb.iotdatas where (serialnum ='0000000000000');`

the result is like this:

[image]
but i want to insert this data into other table using this code

`insert into akdb.climdatas(hightemp,lowtemp,avgtemp,highhum,lowhum,avghum,highpress,lowpress,avgpress,dateinsert,zonedatas)values(maxt,mint,avgt,maxh,minh,avgh,maxp,minp,avgp,datetemp,'zone h');`

here the problem is "maxt mint ..." are unknown, but if i use select into insert

`insert into akdb.climdatas(SELECT DISTINCT date(datecreat) as datetemp
            ,(SELECT max(sensortemp) FROM akdb.iotdatas WHERE date(datecreat)=datetemp ) 
            , (SELECT min(sensortemp) FROM akdb.iotdatas WHERE date(datecreat)=datetemp ) 
            , (SELECT avg(sensortemp) FROM akdb.iotdatas WHERE date(datecreat)=datetemp ) 
            , (SELECT max(sensorhum) FROM akdb.iotdatas WHERE date(datecreat)=datetemp ) 
            , (SELECT min(sensorhum) FROM akdb.iotdatas WHERE date(datecreat)=datetemp ) 
            , (SELECT avg(sensorhum) FROM akdb.iotdatas WHERE date(datecreat)=datetemp ) 
            , (SELECT max(sensorpres) FROM akdb.iotdatas WHERE date(datecreat)=datetemp ) 
            , (SELECT min(sensorpres) FROM akdb.iotdatas WHERE date(datecreat)=datetemp ) 
            , (SELECT avg(sensorpres) FROM akdb.iotdatas WHERE date(datecreat)=datetemp ),' zone h'FROM akdb.iotdatas where (serialnum ='0000000000000000'))`

the error is in the columns   "mysql column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

Comment: What's the definition of the `climdatas` table? Are there any other columns other than the ones you want to insert into?

Comment: ,id,hightemp,lowtemp,avgtemp,highhum,lowhum,avghum,highpress,lowpress,avgpress,dateinsert,zonedatas   but the id increment automatically , i have tested that with values

Comment: In that case, try combining the first insert statement with the second - basically include the list of columns to insert into. At a guess, it's trying to insert into the `id` column as well.

Comment: how can i change` datetemp` column from the first column to the last one??

Comment: See the answer from Keyur Panchal, you just need to move the column around in the list to the position where you expect the data to be.

Comment: it works, thank you for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have more or less than 11 columns in `climdatas` table. In your insert statement, `specify list of columns separated by comma`.

```
insert into akdb.climdatas (dateinsert,hightemp,lowtemp,avgtemp,highhum,lowhum,avghum,highpress,lowpress,avgpress,zonedatas)
(your select query goes here.)
```

Comment: i have used this statement and the same problem, because the result table gives 'datetemp ' in the first column ,like the table above and in 'climdatas',  'dateinsert' column is before last one

Comment: Then change the order of columns. You can do that. See the updated answer. Don't change your select query. Keep it as it is.

Comment: Sure. Welcome. :)

Comment: what if i don't want to repeat the date , how can i do that

Comment: I didnot get you. Would you please describe it more?

Comment: what if i don't want to repeat the date , how can i do that, one time the data are inserted into table in "date",next execute of this query if the date is inserted ,will not be repeated , i think i have to use where not exist but where i have to put it

Comment: It may go at the end of your select query.

Comment: how can i optimize this query , i have lot of data ,

Comment: @lina20: Lina, please add new question with the query that you want to optimize. So that all others including me can view it and help you.